# Authentication through LDAP in Java - Credentials error even with verified credentials

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi

I've got a simple block of Java code which is meant to authenticate a user via LDAP. It's a straightforward function as found on many places online:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String user = "cn=userid@my.domain.net,ou=users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=net";
    String password = "password";
    String ldapHost = "ldap://my.domain.net";
    String ldapPort = "999";
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
         Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
            props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"Simple");
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
            props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost + ":" + ldapPort);

            LdapContext ldapCtxt = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
            System.out.println("ldapCtxt "+ldapCtxt.toString());

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I keep receiving the below error:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

I know this error is a credential error and according to documentation and other forums, hex value 52e means the username is valid but the password is invalid. However, I've also seen evidence that this error will prevent other errors from displaying, and I think it's misleading my debugging efforts.

The credentials I'm using have been verified as correct, and what's more, when I change the username to a nonsense string that *I know is incorrect*, the same error still occurs.

Is there something else that could be causing this error to display besides a valid username and invalid password combination?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `Simple`? Maybe `DIGEST-MD5`?

Comment: @EJP I tried that and got the same error. I failed to mention in the original post, I have this exact configuration doing the same thing in a C# program. Not sure why doing the same thing in Java is resulting in the error